# Apply ggplot to lists of x's and y's

Tags: r, ggplot2, apply

I have a df like below, which x1 and x2 are variables, y1 and y2 are values.

```
ID x1 x2  y1  y2
1   a  T 100  2
2   b  T 210  4
3   b  F 112  5
4   a  F 121  1
5   b  F 412  1
```

I want to make 4 boxplots between them: y1~x1, y1~x2, y2~x1, y2~x2. Any idea to do this?

I have a boxplot function running, similar to

```
boxplot <- function(i,j){
ggplot(df, aes_string(x=i, y=j, col=i)+
  geom_boxplot()
}
```

not exactly the same, but it is tested and functioning like boxplot(x1, y1), etc.
however I do not know how to apply the function to i=c(x1, x2), j=c(y1,y2), to plot all relations all at once. I tried apply, lapply, tapply, mapply, Map.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the x-axis for boxplots is generally a group variable not continuous data

Comment: @rawr yup thats why I have a/b and T/F

Comment: gotcha, i was looking at c(y1,y2)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to `melt` the data twice:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 text = "ID x1 x2  y1  y2
                         1   a  T 100  2
                         2   b  T 210  4
                         3   b  F 112  5
                         4   a  F 121  1
                         5   b  F 412  1")

library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')
mm <- melt(melt(df[, -1], id.vars = c('y1','y2')), id.vars = c('variable','value'))
names(mm) <- make.unique(names(mm))

ggplot(mm, aes(value, value.1)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(variable ~ variable.1, drop = TRUE, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi rawr thanks for your answer! Nice way to use melt and then facet! even solved my formatting problem!